# Rails scope :module filepaths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Regarding the Rails scoped routing, the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) state:

> If you want to route /articles (without the prefix /admin) to 
>     Admin::ArticlesController, you could use:

and then provide the following example:

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :articles, :comments
end
```

So far so good except one minor detail: I noticed that the `ArticlesController` also need to go under `/admin`. In other words for scoping to work I need to do 2 distinct things:

1. Place the `ArticlesController` in a module named `Admin` and turn it to this: `Admin::ArticlesController`.
2. Move `Admin::ArticlesController` from `app/controllers` to `app/controllers/admin`.

I am wondering about the second case here. Why do we have to move the articles controller under an `admin` folder for this to work? Is it not enough that we place `ArticlesController` under a module?

Comment: See this question that was just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453660/do-i-need-to-create-folder-hierarchy-for-nested-module-class-in-rails . The answer is basically the same

Comment: I am still confused...

Answer (score 0):

Found a great explanation to my problem in this blog [post](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/).

It basically sums up to this:

> An unloaded constant `Foo::Bar::Baz` is referenced. Ruby fails to resolve it, and calls `Foo::Bar.const_missing("Baz")`. Rails then:
>
> 1. Looks within autoload_paths for `foo/bar/baz.rb`
> 2. If a matching file is found, it is speculatively loaded:
>
>    - If the correct constant is defined, it is returned
>    - Otherwise, an error is raised
> 3. If no matching file is found, it looks instead for `Foo::Baz`, then `Baz`, unless they are already defined
> 4. If none of the candidate constants can be loaded, it raises a `NameError`